# Remove the tunnel in filter menu in Kendo UI grid

Tags: filter, menu, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added a filter menu in grid column, the content can be filter after fill in the input. And there is tunnel on that column. Actually, it is no need to use in my case. Could anyone tell me how to remove the tunnel ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle for the same

Comment: The funnel icon? Can you write a css style to hide it (i.e. `display:none;`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable filtering of individual column by setting `filterable: false` in the column.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization